# Stata: Reshape command number of j dimensions

Tags: loops, stata, reshape

After reshaping a dataset from long to wide using

```
reshape wide v1 v2 v3, i(i1 i2) j(jdimens)
```

I need to run a loop exactly max(jdimens) times. Example: Assume that the above code creates the new variables jdimens1 jdimens2 and jdimens3. Then I would like to have the loop run three times.

Any ideas how this can be neatly done?

Answer (score 2):

You can count the variables:

```
foreach i of varlist jdimens* {
    di "iteration `i'"
}
```

`reshape` also leaves some characteristics behind that you can use if you don't want to specify names:

```
local myvars: char _dta[ReS_Xij_wide1]
foreach i of local myvars {
        di "iteration `i'"
}
```